# fetch last item in binary data set for display

Tags: swift, fetch, uiimage, binary-data

My swifts code goal is to fetch the last image from binary data pic and display it in imageview picture. Right now its cusing a runtime error with indexpath. I did a similar thing with a string and it worked. The problem is converting binary data to a uiimage.

[image]

```
     var picture = UIImageView()
 var itemName : [NSManagedObject] = []

var itemNamez : [Info] = []

func loadImage(){
    if let imageData = itemNamez[IndexPath.last] {

        let coredataLoadedimage = UIImage(data: imageData)
        picture.image = coredataLoadedimage

    }
}
```

Comment: How is the different than what you asked yesterday? Why post a new question instead of responding to the comments you got on your previous question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i added more information and a picture. I clarified the itemNamez issue.

Comment: You can edit a question once it’s posted you know.